# Long #8-32 screws needed

Tags: screws, furniture, antique

I have an old dresser that has very thick, carved, drawer fronts. One of the long screws that hold the lovely drawer pulls has broken off, and I need a new one that is a #8-32 x 3.25 to 3.5” long.  Anything in that range could work.  My local hardware stores all have #8-32 screws, but none are longer than 3”.  Any idea where to go to find a screw that size, please?

Comment: McMaster-Carr is real world acme.

Comment: Shopping question, so vtc, but the alternative to shopping is to drill deeper into the back of the drawer front to allow the use of a shorter machine screw.

Comment: My favorite supplier: https://boltdepot.com/Machine_screws_Phillips_pan_head_Zinc_plated_steel_10-24. Need _one screw_? They will ship you _one screw_ and at an unreasonably reasonable price. For longer screws, sometimes you have to get a fancy, higher grade steel: https://boltdepot.com/Socket_cap_Alloy_steel_black_oxide_finish_8-32.

Answer (score 3):

Go to a fastener specialist,  or use threaded rod instead.

Comment: This is a shopping question, pure and simple. Please VtC it, instead of answering it.

Answer (score 2):

One assumes that if this site can be accessed, then so can all the online vendors such as [Amazon 8-32 x 3-1/2](https://amzn.to/3SZabH0):

[image: Amazon 8-32 x 3-1/2 screw]

Comment: This is a shopping question, pure and simple. Please VtC it, instead of answering it.